# Spring Boot - Dynamically creating prototype Beans using properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to create prototype beans using some pattern in @Value annotation with properties / yaml configuration?

There is an example what I mean:
Example object:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SomeObject {

    @Value("${someobject.key.name}")
    String name;

    @Value("${someobject.key.address}")
    String address;

    @Value("${someobject.key.phone}")
    int phone;

    getters and setters
}
```

Example properties:

```
someobject.first.name = Phil
someobject.first.address = Berlin
someobject.first.phone = 123

someobject.second.name = Bill
someobject.second.address = New-York
someobject.second.phone = 321
```

I need to create two prototype beans
first with key "first"
second with key "second"
Ideal - if they will initialized like singletons on startup application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you want to use Configuration Properties to allow binding of custom properties to a POJO.

```
package com.darrenforsythe.configurationpropertiesexample;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "properties")
public class MyProperties {



    private Map<String, Person>  someobject = new HashMap<>();

    public static class Person {
        /** Name of the Person */
        private String name;
        /** Address of the Person */
        private String address;
        /** Phone Number of the Person */
        private String phone;

        String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                    ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    Map<String, Person> getSomeobject() {
        return someobject;
    }

    void setSomeobject(Map<String, Person> someobject) {
        this.someobject = someobject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyProperties{" +
                "someobject=" + someobject +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And enable add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)` to your main application or a `@Configuration` class.

AFter this you can inject the `MyProperties` to any Spring bean and use it as any other java object.

For example,

```
    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner printProperties(MyProperties myProperties) {
        return args -> myProperties
                .getSomeobject()
                .forEach((key, person) -> System.out.println(key + " - " + person));
    }
```

Will print each of the items.

Working example can be found here,

https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/configuration-properties-example

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it

I created singleton bean with list of SomeObject

And used @ConfigurationProperties, @EnableConfigurationProperties

How to configure SomeObject:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-list/

4. Binding YAML Lists to Complex Lists

How to work with @ConfigurationProperties:

https://www.mdoninger.de/2015/05/16/completion-for-custom-properties-in-spring-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only need 2 beans, you could do:

```
@Component
class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SomeObject first(@Value("${someobject.first.name}") String name, @Value("${someobject.first.address}") String adress, @Value("${someobject.first.phone}") int phone){
        return new SomeObject(name,adress,phone);
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeObject second(@Value("${someobject.second.name}") String name, @Value("${someobject.second.address}") String adress, @Value("${someobject.second.phone}") int phone){
        return new SomeObject(name,adress,phone);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void init(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        event.getApplicationContext()
             .getBeansOfType(SomeObject.class)
                .entrySet()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}


class SomeObject {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int phone;

    public SomeObject(String name, String address, int phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    // getters setters
}
```

this will print out:

> first=SomeObject{name='Phil', address='Berlin', phone=123}
>
> second=SomeObject{name='Bill', address='New-York', phone=321}

Comment: I looked for solution how to dynamic configure beans in yaml or properties like xml without recompile project, just typing profiles.
Sometimes I need more beans, sometimes less, sometimes no beans at all

Comment: Ok, no problem, if it works for you... But your question states you were looking for 2 beans... The other solutions give you one bean that holds a collection of POJOs.

Comment: Yeah, POJOs is not ideal solution, but it is some compromise. With wrapper bean we can take POJOs by key field